# .dll file is not available

Tags: c#, emgucv

There are some different between emgu cv library , documentation, sample files. emgv.cv.capture  is not supported in latest emgu cv library. I cannot access the _capture.start(), _capture.pause(), _capture.stop() functions. I want solution for this.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that your question was not meant as rudely as you stated it. I will suggest that you check again. In the 3.1 documentation and examples not only is Capture there so is Start and Stop.

Doug